# htaccess and GEOIP infinite loop

Tags: .htaccess, loops, infinite-loop, geoip

I wrote this in my htaccess:

```
GeoIPEnable On 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} PE
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myweb.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !es [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /es/$1 [R,L] 

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css application/x-javascript
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I want users from Peru and another countries to be redirected to http://myweb.com/es

But I got an error:
 http://myweb.com/es/es/es/es/es/es/es/...s/es/es/es/es/ 
How can I fix it?
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead regex to avoid redirecting when it is already `/es/`:

```
GeoIPEnable On 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(es/|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} PE
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myweb\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !es [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /es/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: :( , I got the same error on google chrome, I'v updated my post with the complete htaccess

Comment: For testing just comment out all other rules and keep only this one

Comment: ok, now the page is loading but the url doesn't change it keeps: myweb.com

Comment: ok comment out `RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} PE` line

Comment: I made a mistake, I deleted this line: RewriteEngine On, now the url is myweb.com/es but I got a 404 error.

Comment: ok got it so my suggested rule is working fine. See edited code and uncomment your earlier code.

Comment: :( , now all the images and css don't load. By the way the site uses zend framework

Comment: css/js/images is different problem. just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: wait, it did'nt work out yet, in my html I put this http://myweb.com/theme/default/css/all.css but in the console log I got this: "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://myweb.com/es/theme/default/css/all.css" . The url of my css change to "http://myweb.com/es/" and the images and js is the same

Comment: Now the url doesnt change, it keeps myweb.com

Comment: The thing is my answer solved your original problem long back. I cannot just keep providing you support for other problems. If you have a new problem don't hesitate to open a new question.

Comment: ON stackoverlow you express thanks by accepting an answer. You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.